# Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым 9

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли тире в предложениях типа: Слоган компании (-) "Качество прежде всего"?

Comment: А слово "лозунг" уже вышло из употребления?

Comment: А вам какая разница?

Comment: Разница мне в том, что я не хочу употреблять слова, которые уже никто не поймёт...  Надо привыкать к модерному линго.

Comment: А у компании нет лозунгов. Лозунг - это призыв, в краткой форме выражающий руководящую идею, задачу или политическое требование. А слоган - это сама идея/задача.

Comment: Так и не употребляйте, я-то тут причем? Еще и "линго модерный" какой-то... Что хоть это такое?

Comment: Модерный - ультрасовременный, сиюминутный, насколько я понимаю это слово.  Линго - жаргон, слэнг, **по ходу**.  Нет?  Ну, я, видать, ещё не образовался достаточно.  Займёт какое-то время, но, надеюсь, с Вашей помощью...

Comment: @Vera : 8-O в самом деле? "Слоган" = "идея", а "лозунг" - "призыв", её выражающий?  Ссылка на словарь найдётся?

Comment: @Alenka - вы-то тут при том, что являетесь носителем языка, который для меня новый, и я у Вас хочу научиться.

Comment: Рекла́мный сло́ган — лаконичная, легко запоминающаяся фраза, выражающая суть рекламного сообщения. «Слоган» — термин, перешедший в русский язык из английского, первоначально был распространён среди американских рекламистов. Само слово, однако, весьма древнее, происходит из гаэльского языка (sluagh-ghairm), где означало «боевой клич». В современном значении впервые употреблено в 1880 году. Ну а лозунг на Грамоте.ру посмотрите.

Comment: @Vera : Про рекламные слоганы понятно, спасибо.  Я спрашивал ещё и потому, что у компаний часто бывают "vision statement", который как раз *не является* рекламным слоганом. Правда, они чаще всего немного длиннее, чем, например, "Das Auto".

Comment: Линго - это, как я посмотрела в словаре, профессиональный жаргон. Вряд ли слово "лозунг" можно к нему отнести. Во всяком случае малопонятным его не назовешь. Также могу только догадываться, носителем какого языка в ваших глазах я являюсь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тире ставится между подлежащим и именной частью сказуемого, если они выражены сущ. в И.п. (оно обозначает паузу в устной речи).

Без тире получится не предложение, а словосочетание вида приложение + название.